# Defining URL in CreateEnvironmentRequest of AWS Beanstalk Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I create a new environment in AWS Beanstalk using its Java API, I pass the application name and the new environment name in a CreateEnvironmentRequest to the createEnvironment method.

After the environment is created the URL is something like my-environment-name-wixmmatir2.elastsicbeanstalk.com. But I don't know where the "wixmmatir2" comes from. It seems to be a string with random characters that Beanstalk adds to my URL.

Does anyone know why this happens?
Is there a way to force Beanstalk to respect the name I gave?
I need a predictable URL, such as my-environment-name.elastsicbeanstalk.com, without random characters being added to it.

Answer (score 1):

To create environment with a specific URL you should set CNAME prefix on `CreateEnvironmentRequest`:

```
public void setCNAMEPrefix(String cNAMEPrefix)
```

JavaDoc for the method:
*If specified, the environment attempts to use this value as the prefix for the CNAME. If not specified, the CNAME is generated automatically by appending a random alphanumeric string to the environment name.*

Another helpful method to check if the specified CNAME is available:

```
CheckDNSAvailabilityResult checkDNSAvailability(CheckDNSAvailabilityRequest checkDNSAvailabilityRequest) 
    throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException
```